# Binding a KendoUI dropdownlist on demand

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, html-select

IF I have a kendo dropdownlist as follows

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("products")
      .DataTextField("ProductName")
      .DataValueField("ProductID")
      .DataSource(source => {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetProducts", "Home");
          }); 
      })
)
```

This loads when my page loads. Is there a way to code it such that it only loads when I invoke it to load via javscript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialise DataSource on sever side without executing Read. For eg.,
.DataSource(source => {source.Type = "json"}). On Client side event handler, you can retrieve JSON data using ajax and attach to dropdownlist datasource as :

```
var dataretrieved = <ajax query here>
$("#products").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.data(dataretrieved );
```

Alternatively,

In server side code do not define  datasource. In your client side event handler define the datasource of the dropdownlist. For eg.,

```
$("#products").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
 type: "json",
 data: dataretrieved 
});
```

Note datatype is indicated as part of datasource definition.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to load data first time when you open the dropdownlist, you can set `AutoBind = false` and add an `OptionLabel` like this:
`@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("products")
      .DataTextField("ProductName")
      .DataValueField("ProductID")
      .OptionLabel(new { ProductID = -1, ProductName= "Select Product"})
      .DataSource(source => {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetProducts", "Home");
          }); 
      })
      .AutoBind(false)
)`

You have to be sure to use an option label with `id` and `name`, otherwise it will not be displayed.

Answer (score -2):

Create one JS function and put this code inside in it. and call that function when you need.